# Netsuite way to get [currency] from Account table

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there any way to get [currency] field from Account table in Netsuite?
From record browser both Search Filters and Search Column doesnt included [currency] field.
I need to get the [currency] field from bank type account to do some logic. 
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can't access this field via the Search API but it is available if you load the record.

```
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('account', accountid);
var currency = record.getFieldValue('currency');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. You make me like a fool and thousand thanks.. Appreciated it. :)

Comment: @AhSon You are right to expect it to be available via a search. Unfortunately that's the way it goes with NS sometimes - if the straightforward way doesn't work, try the backwards way..

Answer (score 1):

You could get the accounts and their currencies used thoughout a specific transaction type. For example: this will get you all the accounts and currencies used on Cash Sales:

```
var filters = [];
var columns = [];

filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('type', null, 'anyof', ['CashSale']));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('account', null, 'GROUP'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('currency', null, 'GROUP'));

results = nlapiSearchRecord('cashsale', null, filters, columns);
```

I hope this get you closer to a solution.

Comment: Clever idea. What do you think the performance of this would be versus getting a list of all the Account internalid values and then loading the Account records individually?

Comment: Running a search is a lot faster than loading individual records. Here's another way to do it: http://blog.prolecto.com/2018/07/07/netsuite-suitescript-2-0-lookup-hard-to-search-values/

Comment: Good link, thank you. Second time you've impressed me with an SO answer.